# When adding a comment before down-voting

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Please add a comment explaining..” still shows up when I add a comment and then downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78163/please-add-a-comment-explaining-still-shows-up-when-i-add-a-comment-and-then)
>   [You shouldn’t ask for a comment if the user just voted on a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153528/you-shouldnt-ask-for-a-comment-if-the-user-just-voted-on-a-comment)

Sometimes I find myself adding a criticizing comment to a question right before down-voting it.

Then I get a message encouraging me to add a comment to explain my down-vote, but I already added one!

**Feature request**:
Have the comment encouraging message appear only if I didn't already leave a comment.

Comment: That makes sense and should be easy to implement.

Comment: It's easy to implement, but do we really need to hit the DB one more time just to see whether or not you've left a comment so as not to potentially annoy you a little bit?

Comment: Do it client side. The moment you leave a comment a custom attribute is added to the post. When you downvote, a check is done for the custom attribute before showing the message. This will not work if you 1) wrote the comment 2) visited another page 3)returned 4) down voted. But how common will such a thing be?

Answer (score 3):

On this one I think it's easy enough just to ignore the warning.

Comment: ...or change the behavior.  Downvote first.

Comment: Downvote first, ask question later. Very Clint Eastwood of you, Bill :)

Comment: Why not take this attitude one step further and just slap a "status-by-design" tag on this and be done with it?

Comment: I only left this comment because I can't ignore the warning :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that it should check if you commented already, there should just be a way to link a comment to the downvote, because you may have commented one month before you get the points to downvote something.

Dunno how it will be done.
But for the semantics of the software it should check if you already commented and if so it should not ask you to vote.