# Don't ask for a comment when downvoting, if the user just voted on a comment

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, down-votes

A bit of a nit-picky thing, I don't think I should be asked to add a *comment* if I downvote an answer after having just upvoted a comment to that answer.

[image: pop up of "please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved" and a comment already upvoted]

I already registered my reason for downvoting with the comment upvote, so what you're accidentally encouraging here is a "-1!" or "Me too!"-type comment.

It should be possible to implement this check client-side.

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78163/please-add-a-comment-explaining-still-shows-up-when-i-add-a-comment-and-then

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail, strangely enough, the accepted answer states that this issue has been fixed as of a about 1.5years ago. Not sure what that means, just thought I would point that out for others who may think this is a duplicate/don't want to click the link.

Comment: @kurtzbot: Well, it's a different feature so it would get fixed separately; it just addresses the same kind of issue.

Comment: @kurtzbot: Not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

I agree.  If I've upvoted one of the existing comments on the post, it's quite likely that I've already read those existing comments and decided that one of them already expresses my reasons for downvoting.  At that point, there's no need to nag me to add another redundant comment saying the same thing.

While waiting for this to be fixed, I've added a client-side hack to eliminate these needless nag dialogs into the [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) user script.  It's already in the development branch, and will be part of the next stable release (v1.40).  For the curious, here's the code:

```js
// TODO: add localized message variants?
var re = /^Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved\.$/;
var oldShowInfoMsg = StackExchange.helpers.showInfoMessage;
StackExchange.helpers.showInfoMessage = function ( elem, message, options ) {
    if ( re.test(message) ) {
        var post = $(elem).closest('.question, .answer');
        if ( post.has('.comment-up-on').length ) return null;
    }
    return oldShowInfoMsg.apply( this, arguments );
};
```